# T-SQL Create Id column from a Name column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to separate the name column and create an id column as below:

myTable:

```
name
John F1234567
Mary F7654321
...
```

What I've done until now is:

```
select RIGHT(name,8) as id, name FROM myTable
```

Result:

```
id         name
F1234567   John F1234567
F7654321   Mary F7654321
```

But the result I need is:

```
id         name
F1234567   John
F7654321   Mary
```

I've used some string functions, but no success.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, I give in.. wouldn't it be better if the name and id were separated prior to inserting the record into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using replace function

```
select RIGHT(name,8) as id, replace(name, right(name,8), '') as name FROM myTable
```

Comment: There will be a space after the name here [John ].

Answer (score 1):

REPLACING `right(name,8)` with `''` might not be right way.

```
Select
right(name, 8) as id,
RTRIM(STUFF(name, (len(name) - 8) + 1, len(name) , '')) as name
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select RIGHT(name,8) as id, SUBSTRING(@name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@name)) as name FROM myTable
```

Comment: What if the name is longer than 4 characters?

Comment: Doing this way, some name characters would be missing. See answer above, which worked just fine. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LEFT function with CHARINDEX to get everything to the left of the space.

```
select LEFT('John F1234567', CHARINDEX(' ','John F1234567')-1)
```

Returns `John`

CHARINDEX looks for the specified string and returns its position in the string. I'm assuming this field will always have this space.

Comment: What if name has     'John John F1234567'

Comment: @Pinwar13 true..assumption was made on the data provided by OP

Answer (score 0):

This, like Kannan Kandasamy's answer, will also clean up any leading and trailing spaces.

```
SELECT
RIGHT(name,8) as id
,ltrim(rtrim(replace(name, right(name,8), '')) as name 
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX(' ',name)),SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name),LEN(name)) FROM myTable